# Is there a way to rename images in restAPI local server using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

**i created a localhost api to analyis images and compare them (computer vision) project!**

my plan is to upload images from my data folder to the server, each image file in folder is named (fake_name.jpg/jpeg) i am trying to add the file name as a person name in parameters but can only do it manually and for each file.
i am also trying to figure out how to upload multiple files.

```
    def image_to_base64(self, img):
        # convert image to base64
        prependInfo = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'
        encodedString = base64.b64encode(img).decode("utf-8")
        fullString = str(prependInfo) + encodedString
        return str(fullString)

    # the following part is to create entry in database:

    def create_person_entry(self,img):
        base_url = "localhost:8080/service/api/person/create?"

        parameters = {
            "person-name": 'homer simson' #manual change name from here before each upload
        }
        data = {
            "image-data": self.image_to_base64(img)
        }
        r = requests.post(base_url+urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters),headers{'Authorization':self.auth_tok}, data=data).json()
        return r



#to import 1 image i used:
#with open("///data/homer simson.jpg", "rb") as img:
    person_name = cvis.create_person(img.read())
    print (person_name)
```

it uploads successfuly but i have to manualy name the person entry from parameters "person-name" for each person i upload! researched everywhere to automate solution!

edit1:

i managed to get this code working and it worked

```
# to upload multiple images 
#folder with JPEG/JPG files to upload 
folder = "/home///data/" 
#dict for files 
upload_list = [] 
for files in os.listdir(folder): with open("{folder}{name}".format(folder=folder, name=files), "rb") as data:
upload_list.append(files) 
person_name = cvis.create_person(data.read()) 
print (person_name)
```

i managed to upload all images from directory to server it worked but now all my files are named homer simpson :)

i finally managed to get this right at the suggestion made by AKX his solution is below plz upvote, thanks

Now i need to figure out how to delete the previous no name entries.. will check API documentation.

Comment: I am new to asking questions in community, usually lurking and learning... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something – why not just add another argument to your `create_person_entry()` function?

```
    def create_person_entry(self, name, img):
        parameters = {
            "person-name": name,
        }
        # ...
        return r

# ...

cvis.create_person_entry("homer_simpson", img.read())
```

And if you have a folderful of images,

```
import os
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("people/*.jpg"):
    file_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    with open(filename, "rb") as img:
        cvis.create_person_entry(file_basename, img.read())
```

will use the file's name sans extension, e.g. `people/homer_simpson.jpg` is `homer_simpson`.

Comment: Yes, see above for how to add the person name to the API call and use the filename.

Comment: your code worked! much better and  simpler than what i imagined, thank you for feedback.
If you don't mind i have a question:

1/ at first it didn't work because in my function argument i added name to last argument, but when i did the arguments in the order you specified it worked! why?

2/ why use glob instead of listdir?

Comment: Because it's easier to use for finding files with a given extension :)

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct (the checkmark next to the up/downvote arrows).

Comment: so far i managed to upload one then upload all then delete!! so far so good, but when i try to upload 2 specific images the api fails to read them!? any idea why this code is wrong?

`#with open("/home/data/first.jpg","rb") as img1, open("/home/data/second.jpg", 'rb') as img2:
#    cvis.compare_2images(img1,img2.read())`

Comment: Please ask another question and add your code there. It's nearly impossible to read code in comments.

Comment: i uploaded question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589372/i-am-trying-to-upload-2-images-to-my-localhost-server-using-the-documented-web-a